# Can't check if profile exist in firebase with Angular [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

Please, I need a help, I'm trying to check if the user profile exists in Firebase database with Angular (Ionic). so if it exists then go to TabsPage, if not go to EditProfiePage.

But it didn't work. it's returning null! and always go to EditProfilePage, Please check codes below:

```
this.data.getProfile(<User> event.result).subscribe(profile =>{

console.log(profile);

if (profile.hasOwnProperty('$value') && !profile['$value'] )
{
this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage")
}

else {
this.navCtrl.setRoot("EditProfilePage");
}
```

Data Provider:

```
public getProfile(user: User){

this.profileObject = this.database.object(`profiles/${user.uid}`);

return this.profileObject.snapshotChanges().pipe(first());

}
```

See the picture:
[Picture: The result is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxCVB.png)

Comment: Hossam are you using Firebase Cloud Firestore or RealTime database?

Comment: Hello guardezi, I am using RealTime database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers.

I solved the problem by the following way:

1- I imported Subscription then I declared 'authenticatedUser$' var of type Subscription, then I declared 'authenticatedUser' var of type User (firebase User). - "login.ts"

2- In Constructor I will get current Authenticated User inside 'authenticatedUser$' var, then I will subscribe it into 'authenticatedUser' var. - "AuthProvider.ts"

3- last thing, I will send authenticatedUser var as a parameter to my DataProvider, and also I will subscribe returned value. - "DataProvider.ts"

AuthProvider:

```
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/login-response';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Account } from '../../models/account';

....................

constructor(public auth:AngularFireAuth) {
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }

public getAuthenticatedUser(){
    return this.auth.authState;
  }
```

DataProvider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile';

................

profileObject: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(public database: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  public getProfile(user: User){

    this.profileObject = this.database.object(`profiles/${user.uid}`);

    return this.profileObject.valueChanges();

  }
```

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/login-response';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';

................

user = {} as User;

  private authenticatedUser$: Subscription;
  private authenticatedUser: User;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public toast:ToastController, public navParams: NavParams, public data: DataProvider,
     private myAuthProvider:AuthProvider) {

      this.authenticatedUser$ = this.myAuthProvider.getAuthenticatedUser()
      .subscribe((user: User)=>{
        this.authenticatedUser = user 
    }) 

this.data.getProfile(this.authenticatedUser).subscribe(profile =>{

              console.log(profile);

              if (profile) {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage")
              } else {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot("EditProfilePage");
              }
            });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data provider

Instead of

`return this.profileObject.snapshotChanges().pipe(first());`

You can try

`return this.profileObject.valueChanges();`

Comment: Same thing. it says: "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null".

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check if object has property. A simple if statement is enough.

```
public getProfile(user: User){

  this.profileObject = this.database.object(`profiles/${user.uid}`);

  return this.profileObject.valueChanges();

}
```

The if statement checks if the profile exists or not (If it doesn't exist the result is undefined or null)

```
this.data.getProfile(user).subscribe(profile =>{

  if (profile) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage")
  } else {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot("EditProfilePage");
  }
});
```

Comment: Also the same thing. it says "null". although the profile exists. (https://i.imgur.com/RgebAGJ.png)

Comment: @HossamBrgoth can you console.log() the profiles/user.uid?

Comment: @HossamBrgoth Not that. `console.log(\`profiles/${user.uid}\`)` this will tell if the parameter you're passing is actually present at that point